# Why does the button flicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, controls

I have 2 buttons (custom buttons from now on) added to a button's control (main button from now on) when I enter to the main button I want the custom buttons to have an ImageBackground appear, which is working as excepted. Now, when I enter with the mouse into the custom buttons I want the 2 ImageBackground to appear again and when this happens I want the main button to stay on the same color as it was when I first entered it with my mouse which is happening as I wanted it, but the buttons are flickering AND sometimes when I enter another main button's custom button the previous button is still in the mouseEnter state. Why is that? Do I need to use async/await or something like that?

I think maybe it's because it has to compile when it happens, and it takes a little time and that's why it flickers and that's the reason I think I need to use async/await, but that is really new to me, so I don't know how to use it.

```
public class MyButton : Button
    {
        public MyButton()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick | ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick | ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);

            Margin = new Padding(0);
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
            ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
            TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
            Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 11f, FontStyle.Bold);
            Size = new Size(200, 75);
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
            FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#64A4B3B6");
            FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
            FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);

            Button[] custom = CustomButtons();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Controls.Add(custom[i]);
                Controls[i].MouseHover += CustomOnMouseEnter;
            }

            MouseEnter += OnMouseEnter;
            MouseLeave += OnMouseLeave;
        }

        private Button[] CustomButtons()
        {

            Button delete = new Button();
            delete.Name = "delete";
            delete.Location = new Point(this.Size.Width - 22, 2);
            delete.Size = new Size(20, 20);
            delete.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            delete.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            delete.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#64A4B3B6");
            delete.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;

            Button customize = new Button();
            customize.Name = "customize";
            customize.Location = new Point(delete.Left - 20, delete.Top);
            customize.Size = new Size(20, 20);
            customize.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            customize.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            customize.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#64A4B3B6");
            customize.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;

            Button[] buttons = { delete, customize };
            return buttons;
        }

        private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Controls.Count != 0)
            {
                Controls[0].BackgroundImage = null;
                Controls[1].BackgroundImage = null;
            }

            if (BackColor != ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#64389eed"))
            {
                BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
            }
        }

        private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Controls.Count != 0)
            {
                Controls[0].BackgroundImage = Resources.cross;
                Controls[1].BackgroundImage = Resources.settings;
            }
        }

        private void CustomOnMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#64A4B3B6");
            Controls[0].BackgroundImage = Resources.cross;
            Controls[1].BackgroundImage = Resources.settings;
        }
    }
```

Here is the output of this code [image: output]
you can see the flickering when I enter the custom buttons AND the way the previous button is in the state of MouseEnter even tho I left it!

Every help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you move the cursor over one on the small button, you triger the `MouseLeave` event of the container (the *main* Button), which sets to null the images of the child button. The smaller button `MouseEnter` the resets the images and changes the backcolor of the container (thus, the *flickering*).  When the mouse leaves the smaller buttons area, the container's `MouseLeave` event is not triggered when the cursor doesn't enter its clientarea, thus the darker color persists. It would be easier if you built a UserControl instead of a Custom Control.

Comment: You have a major problem with Graphics objects there. The `Resources` object is a factory: each time you call `Resources.[SomeImage]`, you create a new Bitmap and you never dispose of it, setting instead to `null` the image property of the controls (which does nothing to free the resources previously allocated). You should assign each Bitmaps to a Bitmap object and use this object to assign the Image property of your controls, then dispose of these Bitmaps when you main control is disposed (implementing `IDisposable`).

Comment: And you should not set custom button backgroundImage all the time, but you should change the button's visibility intead.

Comment: @Jimi `You should assign each Bitmaps to a Bitmap object and use this object to assign the Image property of your controls, then dispose of these Bitmaps when you main control is disposed (implementing IDisposable).`
So what I do is, implement IDisposable. So (`public class MyButton : Button , IDisposable`), but other than that, I don't know what to do. Could you please help me out with the code? I'm just a noob here :'(

Also, you said it It would be easier if I built a UserControl instead of a Custom Control, aren't those the same thing?

Comment: @VDN If I change the visibility of the custom buttons, the CustomMouseEnter event won't trigger, even when it's set to visible. I don't know why.

Comment: A Custom Control and a UserControl are not the same thing. You have now a Custom Control, a class derived from an existing .Net native Control (a Button). A UserControl has its own designer, like a Form. You can drop controls on it, define their layout, behaviour, add event handlers. All right, like a Form designer :) You can handle more easily the `Enter` and `Leave` events of the UserControl for example. Try it out: in your Solution Explorer, right click the `Project => Add... => User Control`. I'll see if I can find the time to post an example.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jimi 
I'll do just that! If it's ready, I'll post the thing I created! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that "OnMouseLeave" gets called not only when the mouse leaves the entire control, but also when it enters any of the two small buttons, because they overlap their parent. You should also use "MouseEnter" event instead of "MouseHover".

Below you'll find a bit simplified version that should do the trick. The "inside" field holds the number of "enters" minus the number of "leaves" regarding the whole control. If it's value is greater then zero, the mouse is inside the control, including the two small buttons.

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    Image[] images;
    Button[] custom;
    Color hilited = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#64A4B3B6");
    int inside;

    public MyButton()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick | ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick | ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);

        Margin = new Padding(0);
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
        Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 11f, FontStyle.Bold);
        Size = new Size(200, 75);
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = hilited;
        FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
        FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);

        images = new Image[] { Resources.cross, Resources.settings };
        custom = CustomButtons();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Controls.Add(custom[i]);
            Controls[i].MouseEnter += CommonEnter;
            Controls[i].MouseLeave += CommonLeave;
        }

        MouseEnter += CommonEnter;
        MouseLeave += CommonLeave;
    }

    private Button[] CustomButtons()
    {
        Button delete = new Button();
        delete.Name = "delete";
        delete.Location = new Point(this.Size.Width - 22, 2);
        delete.Size = new Size(20, 20);
        delete.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        delete.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        delete.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = hilited;
        delete.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;

        Button customize = new Button();
        customize.Name = "customize";
        customize.Location = new Point(delete.Left - 20, delete.Top);
        customize.Size = new Size(20, 20);
        customize.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        customize.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        customize.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = hilited;
        customize.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;

        return new Button[] { delete, customize };
    }

    void CommonEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inside++ == 0)
        {
            BackColor = hilited;
            custom[0].BackgroundImage = images[0];
            custom[1].BackgroundImage = images[1];
        }
    }

    void CommonLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (--inside == 0)
        {
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            custom[0].BackgroundImage = null;
            custom[1].BackgroundImage = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, it really does the job! 
That inside count is something that I would have never thought about, it's pure genius! I'm so thankful for your help! I'll remember this method next time if some problem like this occurs!

Thank you again, I'm really grateful! 